# How to get the this DOM Object from the $(this) jQuery Object?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a function to which a jQuery object is passed as an argument. See below code.

```
$('selector').click(function() {
  // $(this) is the jquery object for the DOM on which I clicked.
  test($(this));
});
function test(jqobj) {
  // Here from jqobj, I want to get back the native javascript object (I mean the this)
}
```

Comment: `test(this);`  Seriously???  Or just `$('selector').click(test);` then inside `test()`, `this` is the clicked DOM node. ***WAIT*** Judging by all different answers below, i must missing something really obvious...  Question could be, why would you need to pass the jq object as function param?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The jqobj param is an array of DOM elements so you can use

```
     jqobj[0]
```

but test the size of the array if it is not empty like

```
     jqobj.length > 0
```

Answer (score 2):

So we can covert each other

```
//From jQuery object to Dom:
var domobject = jqueryObject.get();
//From Dom to jQuery object
var jqueryObject = jQuery(domobject);
```

Example:

```
 //From Dom to jQuery object
    var overlayContent = document.createElement("div");
```

Answer (score 1):

```
var __this=this; //declare out side your function.
function test(){
__this; //use __this in your function.
}
```

Answer (score 0):

if you are sure that there will only be one element then

```
function test(jqobj) {
  var el  = jqobj[0]
}
```

Answer (score 0):

rather passing object as a parameter you can also send element id or class to function.Then you can use `getElementById` method inside function to refer the element.

Answer (score 0):

If you are not passing multiple element use like this:

```
function test(jqobj) {
    var obj;
    if(jqobj[0]!=null)
    {
        obj = jqobj[0];
    }
  }
```